# How can I compute the TOTAL of multiple COLUMNS from a PIVOT?

Tags: oracle, aggregate, pivot

I have the following ORACLE SQL table/data:

| A | DATE_FIELD | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-JAN-13 | hello | 0 |
| 2 | 01-FEB-13 | wonderful | 10 |
| 3 | 20-MAR-13 | world | 20 |
| 4 | 21-APR-13 | tree | 10 |
| 5 | 21-JUN-13 | tree | 30 |
| 6 | 01-JUL-13 | world | 10 |
| 7 | 30-JUL-13 | world | 20 |
| 8 | 30-JUL-13 | are | 30 |
| 9 | 30-JUL-13 | world | 30 |

With an example query I'm working with:

```
with 
  data(a, date_field, c, d) as (
    select 1, to_date( '01-JAN-2013'), 'hello',     0  from dual union all
    select 2, to_date( '01-FEB-2013'), 'wonderful', 10 from dual union all
    select 3, to_date( '20-MAR-2013'), 'world',     20 from dual union all
    select 4, to_date( '21-APR-2013'), 'tree',      10 from dual union all
    select 5, to_date( '21-JUN-2013'), 'tree',      30 from dual union all
    select 6, to_date( '01-JUL-2013'), 'world',     10 from dual union all
    select 7, to_date( '30-JUL-2013'), 'world',     20 from dual union all
    select 8, to_date( '30-JUL-2013'), 'are',       30 from dual union all
    select 9, to_date( '30-JUL-2013'), 'world',     30 from dual
  )
  ---
select *
    from ( select c, to_char( date_field, 'dd' ) day, d
              from data 
             where date_field LIKE '%JUL%'  
     ) pivot ( 
       sum(d) for day in ( 
'01' AS "01",/**'02' AS "02",'03' AS "03",'04' AS "04", 
'05' AS "05",'06' AS "06",'07' AS "07",'08' AS "08", 
'09' AS "09",'10' AS "10",'11' AS "11",'12' AS "12", 
'13' AS "13",'14' AS "14",'15' AS "15",'16' AS "16", 
'17' AS "17",'18' AS "18",'19' AS "19",'20' AS "20", 
'21' AS "21",'22' AS "22",'23' AS "23",'24' AS "24", 
'25' AS "25",'26' AS "26",'27' AS "27",'28' AS "28", 
'29' AS "29",**/'30' AS "30",'31' AS "31" 
    ) 
)
```

| C | 01 | 30 | 31 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| are | *null* | 30 | *null* |
| world | 10 | 50 | *null* |

[DB FIDDLE LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/7-QuT0t7)

How can I add a column with the SUM TOTAL of COLUMNS 01,30,31 by modifying the PIVOT or perhaps a using LEFT JOIN? I've been scratching my head with this for almost 5 hours now :(.

Something that would look like:

| C | 01 | 30 | 31 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| are | *null* | 30 | *null* | 30 |
| world | 10 | 50 | *null* | 60 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use the `ROLLUP` GROUP BY function:

```
with 
  data(a, date_field, c, d) as (
    select 1, to_date( '01-JAN-2013'), 'hello',     0  from dual union all
    select 2, to_date( '01-FEB-2013'), 'wonderful', 10 from dual union all
    select 3, to_date( '20-MAR-2013'), 'world',     20 from dual union all
    select 4, to_date( '21-APR-2013'), 'tree',      10 from dual union all
    select 5, to_date( '21-JUN-2013'), 'tree',      30 from dual union all
    select 6, to_date( '01-JUL-2013'), 'world',     10 from dual union all
    select 7, to_date( '30-JUL-2013'), 'world',     20 from dual union all
    select 8, to_date( '30-JUL-2013'), 'are',       30 from dual union all
    select 9, to_date( '30-JUL-2013'), 'world',     30 from dual
  )
  ---
select *
    from ( select c, coalesce( to_char( date_field, 'dd' ), 'TOTAL' ) day, sum(d) d
              from data
             where date_field LIKE '%JUL%'
           group by c, rollup( to_char( date_field, 'dd' ) )
     ) pivot ( 
       sum(d) for day in ( 
'01' AS "01",/**'02' AS "02",'03' AS "03",'04' AS "04", 
'05' AS "05",'06' AS "06",'07' AS "07",'08' AS "08", 
'09' AS "09",'10' AS "10",'11' AS "11",'12' AS "12", 
'13' AS "13",'14' AS "14",'15' AS "15",'16' AS "16", 
'17' AS "17",'18' AS "18",'19' AS "19",'20' AS "20", 
'21' AS "21",'22' AS "22",'23' AS "23",'24' AS "24", 
'25' AS "25",'26' AS "26",'27' AS "27",'28' AS "28", 
'29' AS "29",**/'30' AS "30",'31' AS "31", 'TOTAL' AS "TOTAL"
    ) 
)
```

| C | 01 | 30 | 31 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| are | *null* | 30 | *null* | 30 |
| world | 10 | 50 | *null* | 60 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_H5VMekv)

With the help of `group by c, rollup(to_char( date_field, 'dd' ))`, the derived table additionally produces `TOTAL` rows for each `c`.  Adding a declaration for the `TOTAL` column to the `PIVOT` list ensures that it is included in the output.

Comment: Nice idea, ROLLUP!

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I did see some examples about using ROLLUP but I was not familiar with it. I will definitely have to look at the documentation on how to use that in the future!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option (see lines #16 - 19).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2    data(a, date_field, c, d) as (
  3      select 1, to_date( '01-JAN-2013'), 'hello',     0  from dual union all
  4      select 2, to_date( '01-FEB-2013'), 'wonderful', 10 from dual union all
  5      select 3, to_date( '20-MAR-2013'), 'world',     20 from dual union all
  6      select 4, to_date( '21-APR-2013'), 'tree',      10 from dual union all
  7      select 5, to_date( '21-JUN-2013'), 'tree',      30 from dual union all
  8      select 6, to_date( '01-JUL-2013'), 'world',     10 from dual union all
  9      select 7, to_date( '30-JUL-2013'), 'world',     20 from dual union all
 10      select 8, to_date( '30-JUL-2013'), 'are',       30 from dual union all
 11      select 9, to_date( '30-JUL-2013'), 'world',     30 from dual
 12    )
 13    ---
```

Query:

```
 14  select *
 15      from ( select c, to_char( date_field, 'dd' ) day, d,
 16                (select sum(x.d) from data x                                        --> this
 17                 where x.c = a.c                                                    -->
 18                   and to_char(x.date_field, 'MON') = to_char(a.date_field, 'MON')  -->
 19                ) total                                                             -->
 20                from data  a
 21               where to_char(date_field, 'MON') LIKE '%JUL%'
 22       ) pivot (
 23         sum(d) for day in (
 24  '01' AS "01",'02' AS "02",'03' AS "03",'04' AS "04",
 25  '05' AS "05",'06' AS "06",'07' AS "07",'08' AS "08",
 26  '09' AS "09",'10' AS "10",'11' AS "11",'12' AS "12",
 27  '13' AS "13",'14' AS "14",'15' AS "15",'16' AS "16",
 28  '17' AS "17",'18' AS "18",'19' AS "19",'20' AS "20",
 29  '21' AS "21",'22' AS "22",'23' AS "23",'24' AS "24",
 30  '25' AS "25",'26' AS "26",'27' AS "27",'28' AS "28",
 31  '29' AS "29",'30' AS "30",'31' AS "31"
 32      )
 33  );


C      TOTAL  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
----- ------ --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
are       30                                                                                                                      30
world     60  10                                                                                                                  50
      ------
          ^
          |
       here it is
```